# Changing Browser Title depending on View/API call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I have an ASP.NET application that has two API controllers and API routes:

BurgerController.cs -- `[Route("api/burger")]`

PizzaController.cs -- `[Route("api/pizza")]`

The two routes correspond to two different Pages(Pizza and Burger)

When I switch Views, I want the Browser title to display either 'Pizza' or 'Burgers', depending on the current page/API routes.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Here is my Pizza Controller:

```
public class PizzaController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly string _apiHost;

        public PizzaController()
        {
            _apiHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiHost"].ToString();
        }

        [Route("api/pizza/{groupKey}")]
        public PizzaType Get(string groupKey)
        {

            return CallApiRead<PizzaStats>("/api/pizza/" + groupKey);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There sure is. In your controllers you can do a

```
ViewBag.title="Your Title"
```

before you return the view.

And then in your view you can

```
<title>@ViewBag.title</title>
```

The .title after the viewbag can be anything you want as well. So it could be ViewBag.ThisIsMyTitle

This is helpful when you are using a layout view and have multiple views using that same layout. So you can pass in the title name and have the layout write the tag out.

Hope that helps

Comment: My apologies, I meant to clarify that the controllers are API Controllers and do not return any Views. I will edit my post and include one of the API controllers. Your code, however, does work with my HomeController which does return views, so I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: Then I don't think there is a way to do this in an API response.